# Calculating bearing (magnetic) between two lines?

Tags: bearing, geodesy, web-gis

This should be a basic geodesy question.

I have a requirement to calculate *"bearing (magnetic)"* between two points. 
Will the [igismap Bearing Angle tool](https://www.igismap.com/map-tool/bearing-angle) do the job or is there something more to consider give that there is a requirement for a "magnetic" bearing.

I am hoping for a web based solution.

Comment: If you don't find a web based solution then please use a new question to seek an ArcGIS Desktop one or if this gets no answers you could edit "web based" out and ArcGIS Desktop in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is something more to consider: the Magnetic Declination.

This is a scalar variable, derived from a physical property: the Earth's magnetic field.
It is variable dependant to location and time.

[image: 1]

Magnetic Bearing will be the True Bearing plus the Magnetic Declination, for that point and that date.

**MB = TB + MD**

There are some web resources in the [External links section of the Magnetic declination Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_declination#External_links).

I leave here the link to the [Declination calculator of the National Geophysical Data Center](https://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/geomag/calculators/magcalc.shtml#declination).

Comment: Out of interest, why does the title reference US/UK when it's the entire planet shown?

Comment: The Model is for the World. US/UK are the producers of the information.